# How do shuffle hash join and sort merge join work exactly?

Tags: apache-spark

I can explain how broadcast join works and this article explains it well: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-joins-broadcast.html

But I have failed to find an article that explains the inner workings of shuffle hash join and sort merge join.

Can anyone please give the step by step algorithm for those 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a good material:

[Shuffle Hash Join](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/shuffle-join-spark-sql/read)

[Sort Merge Join](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/sort-merge-join-spark-sql/read)

Notice that since Spark 2.3 the default value of `spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin` has been changed to `true`.

Comment: I guess you meant Spark 2.3